# How to convert a NSUSerdefaults AnyObject? to SWIFT Array so that I can append to it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having some major issues with this. I have a NSUSerDefaults AnyObject and need to convert it to Array so that I can append a string to it.

Even when I cast it as NSArray! at the end of definition, if I try to append to it it seems it is not converted as the error I get says that I cannot append to a type of [AnyObject?]

Can anybody help me, please?

EDIT

this here is how I retrieve the NSUserDefaults and save it to an array to manipulate with it

historyArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("historyArray") as! NSArray

,but when I do
historyArray.append("some string")
I get an error saying: cannot invoke append with an argument list of type (String)

Comment: Try cast it to the array of objects you keep in that array: if var array = arrayWithAnyObject as? [RightType] {...}. RightType is the type you keep in this array (string, int, custom type, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, see explanation is comment:

```
if var myArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("historyArray") as? [String] {
    myArray.append("Something")
    historyArray = myArray
}
```

Comment: I know we are not supposed to post thank you in comments, but you just saved my life big time! You can't even imagine the happinnes I feel right now...